# Use .htaccess to rewrite a sub directory to root but keep access to other sub directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a subdirectory out of my URL structure but have other URLs within that directory structure also work. I have this scenario:

```
// This should load the content of mysite.com/foo/15 but not redirect
mysite.com/foo/ 

// Subdirectories within /15 should also work
mysite.com/foo/bar // the actual location of this is mysite.com/foo/15/bar

// Other URLs within this directory structure should also work, such as
mysite.com/foo/12
mysite.com/foo/13
mysite.com/foo/14

// Lastly, we have redirects from 2012 -> 12, 2013 -> 13 such that
mysite.com/foo/2012 becomes mysite.com/foo/12
mysite.com/foo/2013 becomes mysite.com/foo/13
... and so on
```

Here's where i'm at. I can't get the right combination of htaccess rules to achieve what I want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

// This makes mysite.com/foo/ load the content of mysite.com/foo/15 without redirecting, but makes mysite.com/foo/14 404
RewriteRule ^((?!15/).*)$ 15/$1 [NC,L]

// This works pretty well, except the rules below don't redirect
RewriteRule ^$ 15/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 15/$1

// Rewrite old years to the two digit form
RewriteRule ^2010/(.*)$ 10/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^2011/(.*)$ 11/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^2012/(.*)$ 12/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^2013/(.*)$ 13/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^2014/(.*)$ 14/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^2015/(.*)$ 15/$1 [R=301]
```

What am I missing? What combination of rules will help me achieve what i'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect rules can be combined into single rule using regex matching:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

// Rewrite old years to the two digit form
RewriteRule ^20(1[0-5])/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ 15/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!15/).*)$ 15/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! `RewriteRule ^20(1[0-5])/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]` was pretty smart.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the `L` flag in all your rules and then put all your redirects at the top of the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

// Rewrite old years to the two digit form
RewriteRule ^2010/(.*)$ 10/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^2011/(.*)$ 11/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^2012/(.*)$ 12/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^2013/(.*)$ 13/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^2014/(.*)$ 14/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^2015/(.*)$ 15/$1 [R=301,L]

// This makes mysite.com/foo/ load the content of mysite.com/foo/15 without redirecting, but makes mysite.com/foo/14 404
RewriteRule ^((?!15/).*)$ 15/$1 [NC,L]

// This works pretty well, except the rules below don't redirect
RewriteRule ^$ 15/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 15/$1 [L]
```

Comment: getting an internal server error when hitting mysite.com/foo/14/